# Email not working from Godaddy Server

Tags: asp.net, forms, email, contacts

First of all, I hope to be at the right place, I apologize in advance if this is not the case, please re-orient myself.

So here I have a worry, I have a website www.artipik.com with two forms, online quote and contact form.

My website is hosted by godaddy and servers were updated summers there for 15 days and my form are no longer work, which put me in a very problematic position. I'm a graphic designer not a coder, hence my difficulty changed the code.

I had the godaddy technical service and he gave it to me I think part of the solution. I found the place to change the code, but I can not seem to fit, I'm testing, I no further error messages but I do not receive any email I send.

My current ASP code is as follows:

```
<%
'-----version CDONTS-----
Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
Mail.BodyFormat = 1     '0:html/1:plain text
Mail.MailFormat = 1     '0:MIME/1:plain text
Mail.From = envoyeur
Mail.To = receveur
if copie<>vbnullstring then Mail.Bcc = copie
if sujet=vbnullstring then sujet="Formulaire de contact Artipik.com"
Mail.Subject = sujet
Mail.Body = message
Mail.Send
set Mail=Nothing
'response.cookies("email")=envoyeur
%>
```

and the new code that I have to adapt is the following [(Using CDOSYS to Send Email from Your Windows Hosting Account)](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1073/using-cdosys-to-send-email-from-your-windows-hosting-account?locale=en&ci=46061&countrysite=fr):

```
// language -- C#
// import namespace
using System.Web.Mail;

private void SendEmail()
{
   const string SERVER = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
   MailMessage oMail = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
   oMail.From = "emailaddress@domainname";
   oMail.To = "emailaddress@domainname";
   oMail.Subject = "Test email subject";
   oMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;  // enumeration
   oMail.Priority = MailPriority.High;  // enumeration
   oMail.Body = "Sent at: " + DateTime.Now;
   SmtpMail.SmtpServer = SERVER;
   SmtpMail.Send(oMail); 
   oMail = null;    // free up resources
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Julian

Comment: please dont tag unrelated languages

Comment: basic debugging: confirm that your code is sending the mail. if it is, then you have to move upstream and figure out what's happening with the mail server(s) handling the email. e.g. your code is the equivalent of walking down to the street corner and dropping an envelope into the mail box. if that mailbox later on gets run over by a runaway tank, that's not your code's fault.

Comment: sorry, it's an error

Comment: I have a popup confirming the sending of the message but I get nothing

Answer (score 2):

`System.Web.Mail.MailMessage` is [obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You should use `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` instead. It works almost exactly the same (warning! untested):

```
private void SendEmail()
{
    using (var message = new MailMessage())
    {
        message.From = new MailAddress("emailaddress@domainname");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress("emailaddress@domainname");
        message.To.Add(toAddress);
        message.Subject = "Test email subject";
        message.Body = "Sent at: " + DateTime.Now;
        message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Add this to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="emailaddress@domainname">
                <network host="your-smtp-host-address" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is usually found in the root of your website. If not you can create an empty text file and add `<configuration></configuration>`.

Comment: thanks for your help garry, I demand a lot, but you can write the code for me? I panic

Comment: For the web.config file? You just need to put the system.net section inside the `<configuration>...</configuration>` tags and it will be picked up by the code sample. See the edit

Comment: not only for this part, but for the code that i must addapt, i don't know what i must change in the new code from cdosys, i'm not a coder

Comment: What I've added here should work. You just need to put in your smtp address and change the email addresses accordingly. Try it and let us know if it doesn't work.

Comment: the code you give to me    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage, is a small part or all the code for my asp file?

Comment: Everything in there is what you should need to do what the original code does, but I'm not offering any guarantees ;-) you need to test it and be sure you are happy with it.

Comment: so I created a folder in my webroot with a text file calling web.confing.txt with the code you gave me  then I put another code "System.Net.Mail .MailMessage in my sendmail.asp file "and it does not work

Comment: Hold on. You're putting this in an ASP file? This should go in an ASPX file.

Comment: Your original post give the impression you are converting ASP to ASP.NET. Can I just confirm this is what you are trying to do?

Comment: i'm sorry if i gave you a bad information, at the origin my web site was in asp, you ca verify my site [link](http://www.artipik.com/pages/contact.asp) only the server on godaddy change, that why i have this problem. If you need more imformation tell me..

Comment: The second code sample you gave is ASP.NET, not classic ASP. Where did this come from? Have you been told to use this by Godaddy?

Comment: ah ok i donit know that i'm verry sorry.. go daddy give me this code, it's seems good to me, there is a solution garry?

Comment: Hello Garry i post a new question with more details and all the codage from the asp file in my web site. thanks for your Help. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350999/new-asp-code-for-form-contact-email-on-godaddy-server)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've had the same problem, could solve it throug the next way:

in web.config:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="contacto@mydomain.com">
    <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" password="MyPass" port="25" enableSsl="false" defaultCredentials="false" userName="contacto@mydomain.com"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
 </system.net>
```

in codebehind:

```
       MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
        m.IsBodyHtml = true;
        m.Body = "My Message";
        m.To.Add("jhon.doe@yahoo.com");
        m.Subject = "Go Daddy Emails Go Live!";
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Send(m);
```